# set .dll reference path

Tags: c#

i have used a dll by name(Remoteobj.dll).when i run a project(dll will be in local) but it automatically gets a default location from some other location also copied old dll to local path.but i want to refer to a local path too  how should i do that?

Comment: Are you talking about assembly or maybe unmanaged dll library?

Answer (score 0):

By "used a dll by name", do you mean you are loading the assembly yourself? If so, are you using `Assembly.Load`, `Assembly.LoadFile`, or `Assembly.LoadFrom`? They have different rules for resolving references.

However - in *general* you should consider yourself limited to your own project-tree; otherwise you'll have to start handling `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`.

Or have I misunderstood the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think your after the Global Assembly Cache. Have a look how it works and you realize why you do not want with local dlls.
Have a look at the Wikipedia article about it:
[Global Assembly Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_assembly_cache)